# Jena connection to external databases

Tags: mysql, jena, apache-jena

I have read some articles commenting about the Apache [Jena](https://jena.apache.org/index.html) engine and I have found it really interesting. At their site I have found that in order to store the triples, TDB could be used.

In my case, I would like to know if, from a Jena application would be possible to **load data from external databases such as MySql or PostgreSql** ones, or it is a "closed" product and you can only interact with TDB and Fuseki frameworks.

At the moment, I don't know if the Jena engine framework could act as a traditional Java war but with the particularities of processing RDF files.

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean, connect to existing non-RDF data in MySQL or PostgreSql, then no.  You need to (dynamically or statically) have a conversion layer between the database and Jena.  D2RQ can provide that.

If you mean, use MySQL or PostgreSql to store RDF, then yes.  See Jena SDB.  However, TDB is faster and scales better.

Comment: D2RQ could be used just for read data. So I am afraid the best option would be Jena+TDB, which support transactions: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/tdb_transactions.html . Thanks for the comment.